# Count values in array_agg

Tags: arrays, postgresql, group-by, count, array-agg

Considering the following data:

```
|model| qty | color                              |
--------------------------------------------------
|  y  |  6  | {yellow,red,red}                   |
--------------------------------------------------
|  z  |  4  | {red,blue,yellow}                  |
--------------------------------------------------
|  x  |  9  | {yellow,yellow,yellow,blue,yellow} |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way of counting each "color" grouped in the array below, without using a subquery? (For "y" I would have "yellow:1", "red:2", for instance)

```
SELECT model, SUM(qty), ARRAY_AGG(color) FROM test GROUP BY model;
```

Something like:

```
SELECT model, SUM(qty), ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[color, COUNT(*)::TEXT]) FROM test GROUP BY model;
```

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE test (model TEXT, qty DOUBLE PRECISION, color TEXT);

INSERT INTO test (model, qty, color) VALUES
('x', 1, 'yellow'),
('y', 1, 'yellow'),
('z', 2, 'red'),
('x', 3, 'yellow'),
('y', 1, 'red'),
('z', 1, 'blue'),
('x', 2, 'yellow'),
('x', 1, 'blue'),
('y', 4, 'red'),
('z', 1, 'yellow'),
('x', 2, 'yellow');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. As for me, I don't understand the purpose of the pseudo code.

Comment: No, you cannot nest aggregate functions. You will have to use a subquery.

Comment: @GMB I added some details to the question

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I thought so. Just wondering if there's a workaround without the need for a subquery

Comment: What's wrong with a subquery (or derived table)?

Comment: Why don't you want to just use a subquery?

Comment: You can't do it with a single level of aggregation because you actually want to aggregate on two different levels: first on color level, then on model level. So I don't see any other way than to use a derived table. I would however aggregate this into a JSON object: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8a27e79cce2246b981a6c6fb06ee071a

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select model, sum(qty) qty, array_agg(array[color, qty::text]) colors
from (select model, color, sum(qty) qty from test group by model, color) t
group by model
```

I don't think that there is a simple way to do this without subqueries, and I don't see why you would want to avoid using a subquery in the first place.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ecd91dcdb5f8f394e675335c43ea6180)**:

```
model | qty | colors                       
:---- | :-- | :----------------------------
z     | 4   | {{yellow,1},{blue,1},{red,2}}
y     | 6   | {{yellow,1},{red,5}}         
x     | 9   | {{yellow,8},{blue,1}}
```